# "rxjs" observable.throw is not a function - Angular4

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, throw

I've been learning Angular 4 and everything was going smoothly until I tried to implement catch handling in a service. I'm trying to use "rxjs" catch and throw but I've got an undefined function error in my console.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { AppError } from "../app/common/app.error";
import { NotFoundError } from "../app/common/not-found-error";
import { BadInput } from "../app/common/bad-input";

@Injectable()
export class PostService {
  private url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

 deletepost(post){
      // return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + post.id)
      // Hard-coded id to test 404
      return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + 93498)
        .catch((error: Response) => {
          console.log('error within catch is ' + Response)
          if(error.status === 404)
            return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError(error));

          return Observable.throw(new AppError(error));
        });
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_observable__["Observable"].throw is not a function. 
(In '__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_observable__["Observable"].throw(new 
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__app_common_not_found_error__["a" /* NotFoundError 
*/](error))', 
'__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_rxjs_observable__["Observable"].throw' is 
undefined) — post.service.ts:42
```

I also have this warning in my browser:

```
./~/rxjs/Observable.js
There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* /Users/nickgowdy/Desktop/Angular2/angular4 source code/hello-world/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js
    Used by 14 module(s), i. e.
    /Users/nickgowdy/Desktop/Angular2/angular4 source code/hello-world/node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
* /Users/nickgowdy/Desktop/Angular2/angular4 source code/hello-world/node_modules/rxjs/observable.js
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    /Users/nickgowdy/Desktop/Angular2/angular4 source code/hello-world/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js!/Users/nickgowdy/Desktop/Angular2/angular4 source code/hello-world/src/services/post.service.ts
```

Comment: Try importing `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` with a capital "O" instead of `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';` with a lowercase "o" and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Wow I can't believe that was the reason why. I didn't notice that it was higher case O because it doesn't match the naming convention of all the other imported dependencies. You should post this as the answer so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I've experienced the same thing, the error doesn't always make it clear. Mind if I put that as an answer so that other experiencing the issue may find a solution?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yeah go for it. Create an answer for this question and i'll mark it as correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The error `There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.` is indicating the wrong import is being targeted with how you are trying to use `Observable`.

The import should be with a capital "O" like:

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

This will import the individual `Observable` operator, which be used in combination with operators such as `catch` or `throw` on created Observables.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

To import the full Observable object you'd import it like this:

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'`

**Update:**

With newer versions of RxJS (5.5+) operators such as `map()` and `filter()` can used as [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) in combination with `pipe()` rather than chaining. They are imported such as:

```
import { filter, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Keep in mind terms such as `throw` are reserved/key words in JavaScript so the RxJS `throw` operator is imported as:

```
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
```

**Update:**

For newer versions of RxJS (6+), use this:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
```

and throw an error like this:

```
if (error.status === 404)
    return throwError( new NotFoundError(error) )
```

Comment: Importing the full Observable - import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx' - increases bundle size.
From the docs: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs

To import only what you need by patching (this is useful for size-sensitive bundling):
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

Comment: Yes, `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';` can significantly add to the bundle size as it's importing the full `Observable` object. In most cases I'd argue it's just not needed, but I wanted to provide it as an option as each application is different and may need that kind of control.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky bless you man helped me a lot, whats the difference beween import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable and import {Observable} from "rxjs because i had problem with Observable throw(error) it only worked when i removed /Observable at the end

Comment: @valik Without the `/Observable` it sounds like you are likely importing the full Observable object that includes methods such as `throw`. Depending on your RxJS version, I'd recommend to avoid importing the full `Observable` object and instead utilize [Pipeable Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). Angular has documentation demonstrating using RxJS including using [catchError](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#error-handling) to handle errors. Importing the full `Observable` object brings in stuff you simply may not need.

Comment: //import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; this are the two first doesnt work well with 
  private handleError (error: HttpResponse<Truck> | any) {
    console.error(error.ok || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.status);
  }

Comment: was not able to observe the status code @AlexanderStaroselsky with first one , but i want to know how to use the first one handle error it simply did not work when i changed i was able to observe my errors

Comment: `Observable.throw()` is NOT available for `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` Methods like `throw()` are available on `Observable` when importing the full `Observable` object either through `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';` or simply `import { Observable } from 'rxjs';`.   However you can `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` then `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';` and it should work. Check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1sm1u). I'd also recommend to create a new question to help resolve any specific issues you are having.

Comment: I had to import both `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` and `import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';` to avoid the error message `rxjs observable.throw is not a function`.

Comment: Thank you for sharing detailed information. In my case only **import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';**  didn't work. After that I tried both import line **import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';** and it works like a charm

Answer (score 30):

In RxJS 6, `Observable.throw()` is replaced by `throwError()` which operates very similarly to its predecessor. 
So, you can replace from `Observable.throw(error)` to only `throwError(error)` by importing:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
```

Checkout this link for further reference: https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-6-upgrading-api-calls-rxjs-6

Comment: This saved me! This is the new fix

Answer (score 13):

I was facing the same issue in my `angular 5` application. What I did is, adding a new package.

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

And from my `http` service call I return a function.

```
return this.http.request(request)
      .pipe(map((res: Response) => res.json()),
        catchError((res: Response) => this.onError(res)));
```

And in `onError` function I am returning the error with `throwError(error)`.

```
onError(res: Response) {
    const statusCode = res.status;
    const body = res.json();
    const error = {
      statusCode: statusCode,
      error: body.error
    };
    return throwError(error);
  }
```

Comment: This solution worked in my Angular 6 app w/ rxjs 6.0. My import statement is already import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable' , while doing this I still get the Observable.throw is not a function error. I tried import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw' but it gave a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks Sibeesh !!

Answer (score 4):

_throw has been discarded in newer versions of RxJS 
For newer versions of RxJS (6+), use this:

```
 import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
```

and throw an error like this:

```
 if (error.status === 404)
    return throwError( new NotFoundError(error) )
```

Comment: This worked for me. throwError inherits from Observable so it was a straight swap.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular9 Observable:

1. if data arrived and status is OK, then send the data
2. If STATUS of the data is NOT OK, then throw an error

```
myObsFunc(): Observable<any> { 
  return this.http.get<any>('/api/something') 
    .pipe(
      /* Catch a backend error and let the component know */
      catchError( err => {
        /* Rethrow error */
        return throwError( err );
      }),
      map( (res)=> {
        if( res.STATUS == "OK" ) {
          /* Send DATA to subscriber */
          return Object.values( res.DATA)
        } else {
           /* Inform subscriber that a functional error occured */
           throw ( "getOrphans: Status is not OK but "+ res.STATUS ) ;
        }   
      }),
    )   
}
```