# Angular6 :Property catch does not exist

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new to Angular and I have basic knowledge of it. I want to learn HttpClient so I can create a json file instead of real server. I created a service and imported HttpClient:

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {IEmployee} from "../../../service/src/app/employee";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/index";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

In my class `EmployeeService` I have created a method for getting data from json file:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  private _url: string = "/assets/data/employees.json";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getEmployee():Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url)
      .catch(this.errorHandler);
  }

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return Observable.throw(error.message || "Server Error")
  }
}
```

But in getEmployee method I got these errors:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/employee.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/observable/throw' in 'E:\Tutorial\NodeJS\WebstormProjects\Angular\http\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/employee.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/add/operator/catch' in 'E:\Tutorial\NodeJS\WebstormProjects\Angular\http\src\app'
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

As you can see I have imported `throw` and `catch` operator but I do not know why I keep getting errors.

The other problem is, below `throw method` appear a line because of deprecated(`Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative`)!!
What is the alternative?

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.1
Node: 10.0.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.1
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.1
@schematics/angular          0.6.1
@schematics/update           0.6.1
rxjs                         6.1.0
typescript                   2.7.2
```

****************** EDIT ***************

> I want to use builtin Observable in Angular yet and i do not want to use RXJS third party lib for angular.

This is my node module rx folder and you can see observable file in it.

[image]

And in `node_modules\rxjs\operator` folder there are `throw` and `catch` file..
But why it wants to search these files into `E:\Tutorial\NodeJS\WebstormProjects\Angular\http\src\app` folder that is make a error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed my problem by installing :

```
npm install --save rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6
```

and use this path for rxjs:

```
import {Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from, interval, merge, fromEvent, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from "rxjs/internal/operators";
```

Seems catch depricated at angular 6 so in order to i have used catchError like below :

```
  getEmployee():Observable<IEmployee[]> {
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return throwError(error.message || "Server Error")
  }
```

And all errors gone now :-)

Answer (score 1):

These below references are enough for you. remove unwanted references

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {IEmployee} from "../../../service/src/app/employee";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
```

---

Where,
removed these below references

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

And changed  `"rxjs/Observable"` ainstead of `"rxjs/index";`

### Update:

Should check your `rxjs` folder having these files, if not, then your package has missed something. you need re-install it.

[image]

Comment: I do but in import section i got `TS2305: Module '"E:/Tutorial/NodeJS/WebstormProjects/Angular/http/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable'` @RameshRajendran

Comment: The rxjs folder may missed some folders. So you need to re install the rxjs package. Go https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs

Comment: @RameshRajendran I'm not sure he should remove the operators imports. The latest versions of RxJS rely on the "you use only what is imported" motto

Comment: I am not able to access it from my office @sayreskabir . Sorry I can't see that.

Comment: @RameshRajendran I run `npm uninstall rxjs` and then `npm install rxjs` .but i still got error

Comment: ok try `rxjs/index` instead of that. and let me know what happened

Comment: I still got `ERROR in src/app/employee.service.ts(21,8): error TS2339: Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<IEmployee[]>'.` and red line is blow of `catch` @RameshRajendran

Comment: @sayreskabir and check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45464852/rxjs-observable-throw-is-not-a-function-angular4

Comment: Yes, There are are Observable and Rx file into my project node_modules http://pasteall.org/pic/aa267c517306137424f2cb2dead10229  then why i got error? @RameshRajendran

Comment: Why it look 'rxjs/Observable' here `ERROR in ./src/app/employee.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in 'E:\Tutorial\NodeJS\WebstormProjects\Angular\http\src\app` ?@RameshRajendran

Answer (score 0):

Import these References

```
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {throwError as observableThrowError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators'
```

and then change your code below as

```
getEmployees():Observable<IEmployee[]> {

return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url).pipe(
catchError(this.errorHandler));
}
errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
return observableThrowError(error.message ||"server error");
}
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScaKGrW5s0I&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwhBRAgFinJR8KHIrCdTkZcZ&index=31

if you still not understand check above video link

Answer (score 0):

ErrorObservable creates an Observable that emits no items to the Observer and immediately emits an error notification.

Just import like this

```
 import { ErrorObservable } from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
```

And create error

```
ErrorObservable.create('error');
```